# $http GET returning undefined objects

Tags: angularjs, json

I am currently trying to use the $http service to try and read some JSON files.  I am successfully reading them, but then appear as `object Object` for some reason so I cannot read the properties of the objects.

Am I reading the file incorrectly when I use the `GET` request?  But it's strange because when I use `JSON.stringify()` on the data, I can see all the properties that should be there... it's just when I get it normally they appear as these undefined objects.  Could it possibly be the way that I am initializing the variables?

Here is my function to get the data from the JSON file:

```
myMod.service('deployService', function ($http, envService) {
var projectCache = [];
var envCache = [];
var envFilter = "";

function getDeployments() {
    if (!projectCache) {
        // return;
    } else {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/json_files/dashboard.json'
        }).then(
            function success(response) {
                this.projectCache = response.data;
                this.envFilter = envService.envFilter;

                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    // var item = JSON.stringify(response.data[i].environmentStatuses);
                    var item = response.data[i].environmentStatuses;

                    console.log("THE ITEM IS: " + item);
                    // this.envCache.push(item);
                    envCache.push(item);

                }

                console.log(envCache);
            },
            function failure(reason) {
                console.log("there was a failure in getProject in deployController")
            });
    }
};


return {
    projectCache: projectCache,
    envCache: envCache,
    getDeployments: getDeployments,
    envFilter: envFilter,
    clearCaches: clearCaches
};

});
```

Here is the code for the controller:

```
myMod.controller("deployController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'envService', 'deployService', function ($scope, $http, $location, envService, deployService) {

//store the projects in this array
$scope.projects = [];
$scope.editingData = {};


$scope.selectedRow = [];  // initialize our variable to null
$scope.setClickedRow = function (index) {  //function that sets the value of selectedRow to current index
    $scope.selectedRow[i] = $scope.selectedRow[i] != true;
    console.log(index);
    console.log("row " + $scope.selectedRow[i]);
};


//being used to fetch the name and to get the index
$scope.getProjName = function (index) {
    // $scope.envFilter = {
    //     name: ""
    // };
    console.log("INSIDE GETPROJNAEM");
    envService.clickedEnv(index, $scope.projects);

    //console.log($scope.envFilter);
};



$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: './json_files/dashboard.json'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.projects = response.data;

}, function errorCallback() {
    alert("cant find the dashboard json");
});






//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ENVIRONMENT CONTROLLER LOGIC~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$scope.projEnvironments = [];
$scope.editingData = {};

deployService.getDeployments();
$scope.projEnvironments = deployService.envCache;
$scope.envFilter = deployService.envFilter;
console.log("DEPLOYSERVICE.ENVCACHE: " + deployService.envCache);
// console.log("projenv: " + $scope.projEnvironments);
// console.log("envFilter: " + $scope.envFilter);


$scope.getBranchName = function (environment) {
    envService.setBranchName(environment);
    console.log("THE ENVBRANCH:" + $scope.envBranch);
};

}]);
```

Comment: You need to call the Service from your Angular controller.  You will then be able to read the contents like deployService.GetDeployments()

Comment: @RaniRadcliff yes. I am calling `deployService.GetDeployments()` in my controller, but it is still returning the `object Object`.  Usually when an object is returned there is a dropdown menu in the chrome developer tools, but these objects do not have that either

Comment: @winsticknova Could you update your post with your controller code??

Comment: @EvanBechtol posted the controller.  the call to the function is right below the "environment controller logic" comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your service as a dependency in your relevant controller. Then, call the appropriate method from your service inside the controller.

For example:

```
myApp.controller('aController', ['$scope', 'deployService', function ($scope, deployService) {
    //Some $scope variables and other controller code
    deployService.getDeployments();
    $scope.myData = deployService.<variable from service>;
}] );
```

Also, be careful when assigning variables to arrays in javascript; the assignment will be done by reference, not by value! This can produce undesired results if not accounted for.

Comment: I added the service to my controller already.  I have no problem calling the functions in the service - it's just the return object's properties from the GET request can't be read for some reason.  Everything seems to be undefined.

Comment: @winsticknova Sounds like a problem on the back-end, if the results are not correct in the GET request. What framework or language are you using on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

try re-writing your code in your controller like this:

```
deployService.getDeployments()
.success(function(data){
$scope.myData = data;
})
```

If hovering over `$scope.myData` doesn't show you an array of objects there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual json object returned from server in `$http` request is `response.data`.

if your json contains a "data" property as array, you need to iterate over that as;

```
response.data.data.forEach(
    d => JSON.stringify(d.environmentStatuses)
)
```